# How to update token name in solana token 2022 program

Tags: solana-cli, token, token-2022

i was trying to update name and symbol etc i tried enable metadata and update and when i use spl-token display  in extensions it shows fine but on solscan or wallets name is unrecognized token how to fix this problem

Comment: I am also interested in this, cant find solution for days!

Comment: make sure you have given the right url link, open that link in your browser and verify that it gives raw json data.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Token22 metadata standard is not supported by the block explores. You will still need to use a metaplex pointer if you want the things to come up on Solscan.

I had this same issue a couple of days ago, but i still cant figure out how to create a metaplex pointer, so please let me know if u firgure out how.